# How to customize unmanagedResourceDirectories and excludeFilter in Play Framework 2.2?

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, mybatis, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to integrate MyBatis with Play Framework 2.2 according to the [guide](http://www.inoio.de/blog/2013/02/07/integrating-mybatis-guice-play2/).
This guide is written for Play v2.1.x that uses `project/Build.scala` instead of `build.sbt`.

How can I add mapper xml files to classpath in this case?

Excerpt from the configuration used in article below:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  // Add app folder as resource directory so that mapper xml files are in the classpath
  unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= baseDirectory( _ / "app" ),
  // but filter out java and html files that would then also be copied to the classpath
  excludeFilter in Compile in unmanagedResources := "*.java" || "*.html"
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Settings just go in the `build.sbt` file with an extra newline in between them instead of the comma, so:

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= baseDirectory( _ / "app" )

// but filter out java and html files that would then also be copied to the classpath
excludeFilter in Compile in unmanagedResources := "*.java" || "*.html"
```

The blank line is required!

Comment: Robin thanks very much! Does it matter whether I put them before or after `play.Project.playJavaSettings`?

Comment: No, I don't think the order ever matters.